# regular expressions: in a JSON array, get the id of the object that has status waiting

Tags: regex, json, jmeter

I have a JSON response that I want to parse with regular expressions that contains an array of objects like

```
...
{
 "Id":"01",
 "Subject":"Sub",
 ....
 "Status":"Completed"
 ...
},
{
 "Id":"02",
 "Subject":"Sub",
 ....
 "Status":"Waiting"
 ...
}
```

and I want to get the id of the object that has status waiting.

When I parse with `"Id": "(.+?)",[\s\S]+?"Subject": "Sub",[\s\S]+?"Status": "Waiting";` it matches from "Waiting" to the first "Id" (backwards); certainly I want the Id of the object that is waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{\s*"Id":"(\d+)"[^}]+"Status":"Waiting"\s*}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
(?s)"Id":\s*"([^"]+)[^}]*?"Status":\s*"Waiting"
```

It will work if there is no nested { } between properties Id and Status.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a Json Parser, please use that.

This will work as long as there are no nested brackets.

```
{[^{}]*Id":"(\d+)[^{}]*\s"Status":"Waiting"
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?31pvg)

Your expression

```
"Id": "(.+?)",[\s\S]+?"Subject": "Sub",[\s\S]+?"Status": "Waiting"
                                       ^^^^^^^^
                                       fails here
```

That part matches anything from the first `"Sub",` till it finds the first `"Status": "Waiting"`